# How to get logged user roles through API- Sensenet

Tags: sensenet

I need to get the role of user who logged in to provide role based functionalities. Iam unable to get the type of role from API. is there any method to get the logged user role through API?

Comment: Do you mean on server or client side? C# or JS? :)

Comment: @MiklósTóth We are using React for front end. To be specific I have a create directory button in front end. Only Certain users with certain roles should be able to use this. That means for other users this button should be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the user's Path you can use the `GetPermissions` action:

```
http://example.com/OData.svc/workspaces/Project('budapestprojectworkspace')/GetPermissions?identity=userPath
```

Check the docs [here](https://community.sensenet.com/docs/built-in-odata-actions-and-functions/#get-permissions)

Comment: I need it for a button in front end. Not for any content.